# Invalid string length error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have map in my View

In popups for marker, I show info

In `json[i].rating` I have number from 1 to 5 and now I show it. But I need to show rating star image for example this

[image]

So if I have for example 2 in rating, I need to have two stars.

How I can do this correctly?

Here is working snippet of what I have now

```js
$(function() {
  const json = [{
    "name": "Park Hotel",
    "address1": "327 Cranbrook Road",
    "rating": 2,
    "lng": 0.065,
    "lat": 51.568,
    "pictures": [{
        "url": "https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/003/623/222/LON-91B-1.jpg?1387213390",
        "description": "Exterior"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/003/623/225/LON-91B-2.jpg?1387213390",
        "description": "Lobby"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/003/623/227/LON-91B-3.jpg?1387213390",
        "description": "Lobby"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/003/623/230/LON-91B-4.jpg?1387213391",
        "description": "Lobby"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/003/623/232/LON-91B-5.jpg?1387213391",
        "description": "Guest Room"
      }
    ],
    "sales_price": 2847
  }];
  const star = `
<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dzwdseno3/image/asset/f_auto/star-bb0cd011d3d4aa12c83109f30c6c17ed.png">
`;
  const token = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibmVtZXNpc2VzIiwiYSI6ImNqaDlqaDQycTA1ZnEzY3BpbDZpNHk1c2EifQ.KbuJOIjYh6VrWYo48yxETg';

  mapboxgl.accessToken = token;

  let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map-canvas',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [0.065, 51.568],
    zoom: 3
  });

  map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
  $.each(json, function(i, item) {
    let myLatlng = new mapboxgl.LngLat(json[i].lng, json[i].lat);
  let stars = '';
for(let s = 0; i < json[i].rating; s++) {
    stars += star;
}
    let marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
      .setLngLat(myLatlng)
      .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({
          offset: 25
        })
        .setHTML('<h3 class="hotel_name">' + json[i].name + '</h3><p class="adress-text-hotel">' + json[i].address1 + '</p>' + '</h3><p class="rating-title">Reting: ' + json[i].rating + '</p>' + '</h3><p class="price-text-hotel" >Price ' + stars + '</p>'))
      .addTo(map);


  });
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}

#map-canvas {
  width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.45.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.45.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

I tried this one example and I have

> Invalid string length error

Comment: Can you reduce your code to just the specific problem?  If it's related to the data returned, then update to include some sample data.  As it is, it's not possible to even tell where you are getting your error. Have a read of [mcve].

Comment: what line does the error appear on?  also why not use item instead of json[i]?

Comment: I updated my post. Check it. @freedomn-m

Comment: I updated post. Run Snippet @Pete

Comment: print the data[i].rating also as a data-* attribute of a span element, then style the span with a background of repeated stars according to the data-* attribute.

Comment: typo - you use i instead of s - `(let s = 0; i < json[i].rating; s++)` should be `(let s = 0; s < json[i].rating; s++)`, change it and your code will work

Comment: Oh sh*t , really . Thanks!!!! @Pete

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for:

```
star.repeat(json[i].rating)
```

Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```js
var hotels = [
 {
   name: 'Hotel-1',
    rating: 3
  },
  {
   name: 'Hotel-2',
    rating: 5
  }
];

var content = document.querySelector('.content');

hotels.forEach(function(hotel) {

 // Add div.star's depending on rate
 var htmlStars = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < hotel.rating; i++) {
   htmlStars += '<div class="star"></div>';
  }
  
 var htmlHotel = `<div class="hotel">
   <span>${hotel.name}</span>
   ${htmlStars}
  </div>
  `;

  content.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlHotel);
});
```

```css
.hotel span {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.star {
  display: inline;
}

.star::after {
  content: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dzwdseno3/image/asset/f_auto/star-bb0cd011d3d4aa12c83109f30c6c17ed.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
</div>
```